# 複数Nodeからの署名収集時のFlowについて

Tags: java

複数Nodeから署名を集める場合のFlow実装について教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0):

CE/COS4.4までは複数のNodeから署名を集める場合、Flow APIsはシーケンシャルに署名を集める実装となっているため、多数のNodeから署名を集める際のレイテンシ増加が懸念されていました。
これに対し、CE/COS4.5で署名対象のNode(requiredSigner)が複数いる場合、各Nodeから並列に署名を収集する機能（SendAll/SendAllMap）が追加され、CE/COS4.4以前のバージョンで懸念されていた複数Nodeから署名を集める際のレイテンシ増加への懸念が軽減されました。
詳細については下記、公式ドキュメントをご参照下さい。

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.8/cordapps/api-flows.html#communication-between-parties